# Access SQLで、二つのテーブルを比較し、片方にしかない方のデータのみを取得する方法について

Tags: sql, ms-access

お世話になります。

初歩的な質問ですみません。

Access2010を使用しています。
基本となるAテーブルと、比較するBテーブルのidを見て、AにはあるがBにはない
レコードのみを抽出するSQLを作成しています。

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE ISNULL(B.id) = TRUE
```

…と、方法自体は間違っておらず、結果も正しいものを取得できてはいるのですが、
A,B共に件数が六万件以上あり、このクエリひとつで30秒ほど時間がかかって
しまいます。

もっと高速に動作する方法はないでしょうか？

一つの方法として、一度中間テーブルのCを用意し、

```
    ① INSERT INTO C (id) SELECT id FROM A
    ② DELETE * FROM C WHERE EXISTS (Select * From B Where C.id = B.id)
③SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN C ON a.id = C.id
```

としてみたところ、若干早くなったような気はしますが、やはり実用的な
レベルではありませんでした。

良い方法がありましたらご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQLの特性が分からないので思いつくSQL文を列挙してみます。どれが速いか比較してみてください。

左結合で一致しなかった行を抽出（27秒）

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Bのid一覧を作成し、そこに含まれていない行を抽出（55秒）

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B)
```

Bにidの一致する行が存在しないAの行を抽出（14秒）

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id)
```

コメントよりAccessでの実行時間を参考値として記載しました。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。本日、やっとのことで比較が終わりました。それで、頂きました方法を上から順に行ってみたところ、左結合 = 27368.4726m秒、一覧に該当しないケース = 55086.5081m秒、NOT EXISTSを使用した場合、14217.4216m秒と、それぞれ倍近い差が出たことがわかり、結果としてNOT EXISTSを使用するのが最も効率が良かったということになりました。まだ満足という感じではないですが、件数の多さからこれは仕方がないのかもしれません。ありがとうございました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。